# VMware issue after Kernel Update

Tags: networking, kernel, vmware, vmware-tools

has anyone had an issue with VMware after updating to Linux A 5.0.5-050005-generic?

I have tried everything, I can think of and find.
Thanks.

```
Makefile:1553: recipe for target 'module/tmp/modconfig-BK55kF/vmnet-only' failed make[1]: 
* [module/tmp/modconfig-BK55kF/vmnet-only] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.5-050005-generic' Makefile:110: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed make: 
* [vmnet.ko] Error 2 make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-BK55kF/vmnet-only' 

Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon      done
   VM communication interface socket family      done
   Virtual machine communication interface      done
   Virtual machine monitor      done
   Blocking file system      done
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor     failed
   Virtual machine communication interface      done
   VM communication interface socket family      done
   Blocking file system      done
   Virtual ethernet     failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon      done
```